# Why Viewbag not show in asp.net mvc view page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I'm beginner in asp.net mvc,write this java script code for fetch any data from controller:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("CallService", "MyScore")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        'id': 29
    },
    success: function(color) {
        //alert(color);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error occured');
    }
});
```

and write this action in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CallService(string id)
        {

            var idNum = Convert.ToInt32(id);

            string color = idNum.ToString();
            ViewBag.Myfamily = "razzaqi";

            return Json(color, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

in view page write this code:

```
<h1> Hello Dear @ViewBag.Myfamily</h1>
```

when i run the project `<h1> Hello Dear @ViewBag.Myfamily</h1>` not show me ,but i think show me this output:

```
Hello Dear razzaqi
```

Comment: Because you sending back `json` (not the `ViewBag` value). And change the parameter to `int id` if you expecting `int`

Comment: @StephenMuecke how can return viewBag value?

Comment: Don't use `ViewBag` - is you want to return `"razzaqi"` to the view use `return Json("razzaqi", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and then in the ajax success callback, update the DOM - e.g. `success: function (data) { $('#someElement').html(data); }`

Comment: Just for information, if you want to use viewbag , you will have to return the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning JSON not `ViewBag`. You need to send the `"razzaqi"` to as part of JSON object.  Set up HTML as

```
<h1> Hello Dear <span id='familyname'></span></h1>
```

Modify You controller to return `myfamily` as part of JSON object.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CallService(int id)
{
    string color = id.ToString();

    return Json(new {
        color = color
        myfamily = "razzaqi"
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Consume the result like

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("CallService", "MyScore")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: { 'id': 29 },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#familyname').text(data.myfamily)
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error occured');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Viewbag object is filled into the view, server side when making the view. Your ajax call contacts the server asking about Json data **after the view is already made**.

So you are too late passing objects to your viewbag if you do it this way...

---

There are however some workarounds/solutions for this problem:

1. Let the Controller return the variable in the Json it's returning.

   - Simple, efficient way to get the data you need
   - Html helpers etc. Won't work however and sometimes you just need that horrible viewbag...
2. Reload a partialview when doing the ajax call.

   - Takes more time to implement, You'll have to create a new action and partialview.
   - Good when you want more content to change on the call and want to use html helpers etc.